# where to download Camtasia for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-center

I used Ubuntu before and it was great, but there was a big problem - there was no Camtasia video editor, and it is very important to me for editing, since it was the easiest editor. Where to download Camtasia for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

Quote from https://www.techsmith.com/video-editor.html

*Camtasia makes it simple to record and create professional-looking videos on Windows and Mac.*

So there is NO Linux version of Camtasia, but there is some alternative like:

- Kdenlive
- PiTiVi
- OBS Studio
- Shotcut
- OpenShot
- Cinelerra

Read more about them here: https://ubunlog.com/en/los-mejores-editores-de-video-gratuitos-para-ubuntu/